# PYTHON 3 Using URLLIB2 to authenticate on a site where SID changes at every login?

Tags: python, urllib2

I'm trying to get some data out of a Webinterface on a Solar Inverter. The Web UI is basic HTML5.

But, how do i do that with URLLIB2, because everytime i logon, i get a new SID, something like  "sid=6275038569783222283"

This SID is placed after every sources i want to view, which could be like this:

```
 <td width="750"><iframe id="mainFrame" name="main" src="/cgi-bin/overview.tcl?sid=6275038569783222283" width="740" height="410" frameborder="0" align="right" scrolling="auto" allowTransparency="true"></iframe></td>
```

when opening the /cgi-bin/overview.tcl?sid=6275038569783222283 i get the data i want.

But how do i get URLLIB2 to use a SID generated at every login?

Comment: There is no urllib2 in python 3.

Comment: No, i've just read that... But then with URLLIB? Or is it possible to install URLLIB3 in python3?